# How do I get the last function wait for the two coroutines above it in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an `init{ }` block in a viewModel in Android.

In the `init` block, I want to first check if we have names that we've already downloaded from an API. If we have the names, we pick one of them randomly. If we don't, we download names and push them into a list in the `nameState` data class and then we can pick one name randomly using the `getOneName()` function.

My problem is that in the `init` block, nothing I try makes the `getOneName()` function wait for the `downloadNames()` and `updateState()` functions to finish.

Note: the `downloadNames()` and `updateStateWithNames()` functions do work. I can tell because I have a button in the app that when pressed, runs the `getOneName()` function successfully. However, I want the `getOneName()` function to also work at the start of the app.

My initial attempt was the below code after reading that, in a coroutine scope, the functions would be performed synchronously. But still, the last function ended up with no data.

```
init{
   launch{
      getOneName()
      downloadNames()
      updateStateWithNames()
   }
}
```

Here is the code of my latest attempt

```
private val _nameUIState = mutableStateOf(NameState())
val nameUIState: State<NameState> = _nameUIState

private var getNamesJob: Job? = null

init{
   if(_nameUIState.value.names.isNotEmpty()) {
      getOneName()
   }else {
      viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
         val job = launch {
            downloadNames() // in the definition of this function, it is also launched within viewModelScope
            updateStateWithNames()
         }
         job.join()
         getOneName()
      }
   }
}

private fun getOneName() {
        val idx = Random.nextInt(_nameUIState.value.names.size)
        val name = _nameUIState.value.names[idx]
        _nameUIState.value = nameUIState.value.copy(pickedName = name)
    }

private fun downloadNames() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            namesUseCases.downloadNames()
        }
    }

private fun updateStateWithNames() {
        getNamesJob?.cancel()
        getNamesJob = namesUseCases.getAllNames() // Flow is returned here
            .onEach { namesList ->
                _nameUIState.value = nameUIState.value.copy(names = namesList)
            }
            .launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

Comment: Can we see what these three functions look like so we can see what's synchronous/asynchronous and what's a suspend function or not? You probably defined one or more of your functions as asynchronous instead of making them synchronous.

Comment: @Tenfour04, I've added the definitions of the functions with some descriptions

Comment: I guess I also need to see the type of your `nameState` and `nameUIState` to be able to write a complete answer. Like what type of class are in these StateFlows (I'm assuming they are StateFlows), or are they Compose MutableState?

Comment: Also, is `namesUseCases.getAllNames()` a flow that monitors a database that you are putting the downloaded names into? If not, can you show the whole use case class?

Comment: @Tenfour04, I really appreciate your support on this. I have edited the submission to combine everything and provide more information. Also, yes, the ```getAllNames()``` is a Flow because it returns the output of this function in the repository```fun getAllNames(): Flow<List<Name>>```. Also, I have edited the ```nameState``` to ```nameUIState``` for uniformity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch a coroutine inside a function like this, you have made the function asynchronous:

```
private fun downloadNames() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        namesUseCases.downloadNames()
    }
}
```

If the function is asynchronous and has no callback parameter, it is impossible for the to call it and wait for its result. Since it is calling a suspend function, the way to make this function synchronous is to mark it as a suspend function, so redefine it like this:

```
private suspend fun downloadNames() {
    namesUseCases.downloadNames()
}
```

The above assumes that `namesUseCases.downloadNames()` is a proper synchronous suspend function. I can't tell without seeing it. If it's not, it breaks convention and needs to be fixed.

---

As for waiting for the flow, that's not so clear cut. You need to decide if you're wanting to do this imperatively or reactively. Since it is based on a Flow this lends towards a reactive solution.

In general, imperative code tends to end up being more complicated to manage because your logic has to proactively do things and coordinate events in multiple places.  It looks fine when all you're doing is showing the current data one time and it will never change while this screen is in view, but otherwise reactive code is easier to maintain.

Imperative code might seem more intuitive if you're new to programming, and it will be fine for simple situations. It might be perfectly appropriate for this situation, if you are not expecting the list of names written to the database while this screen is open, so you aren't wanting to change the list of names and selected name each time it updates.

---

#### Imperative solution

To make `updateStateWithNames()` syncrhonous, you can get the first value returned by your flow by calling `first()` on it. Then you can make `updateStateWithNames()` an imperative and synchronous function like this:

```
private suspend fun updateStateWithNames() {
    val namesList = namesUseCases.getAllNames().first()
    _nameState.value = nameState.value.copy(names = namesList)
}
```

Now both of the functions are synchronous suspend functions, so your `init` block can do the behavior you described like this:

```
init {
   if(_nameState.value.names.isNotEmpty()) {
      getOneName()
   }else {
      viewModelScope.launch {
         downloadNames()
         updateStateWithNames()
         getOneName()
      }
   }
}
```

---

#### Reactive solution

In this case it doesn't even matter if `downloadNames()` is synchronous or not. You can simply call it in your `init` block to initiate that your use case will ensure a list is retrieved. All it does is start the use case class on initiating the download and updating the flow it will return. You would use `getOneName` as part of collecting this flow. There are a few different ways you could do it. Here's one:

```
private val _nameUIState = mutableStateOf(NameState())
val nameUIState: State<NameState> = _nameUIState

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        namesUseCases.downloadNames()
    }

    namesUseCases.getAllNames()
        .onEach { namesList ->
            _nameUIState.value = nameUIState.value.copy(names = namesList)
            if (namesList.isNotEmpty()) {
                getOneName()
            }
        }
        .launchIn(viewModelScope)
}

private fun getOneName() {
    val names = _nameUIState.value.names
    if (names.isEmpty()) {
        return
    }
    _nameUIState.value = nameUIState.value.copy(pickedName = names.random())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making your jobs Asynchronously now, because each function has been set up with a different launch builder.

As the official doc says: launch is a coroutine builder. It launches a new coroutine concurrently with the rest of the code, which continues to work independently.

if you wanna wait for each job you should implement them in one coroutine builder.

There are other approaches that you can try according to what you need like async.